# Monitoring battery or power supply of laptop from java

Tags: java, hardware-interface

I am developing an application which monitors the presence of the power supply of the laptop. If there is a power cut or restoration it will intimate me over email. It will also application monitoring and controlling over email (Basically to control my laptop from my office over email). I am done with email interfacing but I have no idea on how to monitor the power supply / battery supply from java.

If any can give some pointer on this it will be of great help.

Thanks in advance ....

Comment: It would help to know the platform (OS) since this is likely platform specific.

Comment: just curious why u use the verb intimate there? It sounds odd. did you mean to use another word or is that some sort of email api?

Comment: I am using windows vista and for the "intimate" was a typo should have been "inform" :$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have probably already solved this problem but for the others - you can do it the way Adam Crume suggests, using an already written script [battstat.bat](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/files/battstat_xp.txt) for Windows XP and higher.
Here is an example of the resulting function:

```
private Boolean runsOnBattery() {
    try {
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c battstat.bat");

        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

        String s;
        while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            if (s.contains("mains power")) {
                return false;
            } else if (s.contains("Discharging")) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Or you can simplify the script to return directly True/False or whatever fits.

Comment: This is quite interesting, although it is not giving battery's current status properly this is exactly what I was looking for back then.

Answer (score 2):

On linux, you can use /proc/acpi/battery/

Answer (score 1):

A quick google search turns up a [java acpi library on sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacpi/).  Hasn't been updated since 2004 though.

Answer (score 1):

Here's code that works on Windows by using the [`SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373232%28VS.85%29.aspx) structure.

Note that you need to add [`jna`](https://github.com/twall/jna) to your (Maven) dependencies for this to work.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Structure;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;

public interface Kernel32 extends StdCallLibrary
{
    public Kernel32 INSTANCE = (Kernel32) Native.loadLibrary("Kernel32",
            Kernel32.class);

    public class SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS extends Structure
    {
        public byte ACLineStatus;

        @Override
        protected List<String> getFieldOrder()
        {
            ArrayList<String> fields = new ArrayList<String>();
            fields.add("ACLineStatus");

            return fields;
        }

        public boolean isPlugged()
        {
            return ACLineStatus == 1;
        }
    }

    public int GetSystemPowerStatus(SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS result);
}
```

In your code call it like this:

```
Kernel32.SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS batteryStatus = new Kernel32.SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS();
Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetSystemPowerStatus(batteryStatus);

System.out.println(batteryStatus.isPlugged());
```

Result:

```
true if charger is plugged in false otherwise
```

This has been derived off [BalsusC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434719/how-to-get-the-remaining-battery-life-in-a-windows-system).

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty way to handle this is call a native program (via Runtime.exec(...)) and parse the output.  On Windows, the native program might be VBScript that uses WMI.