# Get Windows Charging Status in Java

Tags: java, windows, jna, battery

I am trying to tell weather or not my windows laptop is charging. I want it to check, and return either a 1 or true if it is charging or a 0 or false if it is not. I am following the instructions at [How to get the remaining battery life in a Windows system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434719/how-to-get-the-remaining-battery-life-in-a-windows-system), But I can't figure out how to parse the answer and get the charging status. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Edit: I want to be able to type something like 
boolean battery = getBattery();
and have it return true or false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `getBatteryFlagString()` method from the referred [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3434962/1613867). Or use directly the `BatteryFlag` and check if it's equal to `8`, see `getBatteryFlagString` for details.

Something like:

```
Kernel32.SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS batteryStatus = new Kernel32.SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS();
Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetSystemPowerStatus(batteryStatus);

boolean battery = batteryStatus.BatteryFlag==8;
```