# Java, manage battery on laptop

Tags: java, battery

I would like to manage the battery of my laptop. I want to create a program in java.

I did a lot of research but I do not find it there's a possible way to be able to block the loading of the battery, in java ?

Maybe you could oriented me?

Thank you very much in advance !

Comment: What does "block the loading of the battery" even mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont't think thats possible using only java, because the information about the battery status is available in the operating system only.
I recommend you ready this article:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3434962/3234981

It describes how to manage the access to the battery, using `JNA`.
So if you want to access the battery, this would be the way to go.