# Windows Kernel32.BatteryLifePercent = 255

Tags: windows, windows-7-x64, jna, battery, kernel32

I'm trying to build a Java app that reads the status of a laptop battery and sends a notification to the user if it's low. In order to do this, I'm using jna with Kernel32 native library as explained in the first answer of this question:
[How to get the remaining battery life in a Windows system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434719/how-to-get-the-remaining-battery-life-in-a-windows-system)

Running the example, the program yields this output:

```
ACLineStatus: Offline
Battery Flag: High, more than 66 percent
Battery Life: Unknown
Battery Left: 0 seconds
Battery Full: 10832 seconds
```

The fields battery life and battery left are read in Kernel32 *BatteryLifePercent* and *BatteryLifeTime* values which are 255 (Unknown) and 0 (I don't get this value. Unknown would be -1 according to Microsoft documentation here: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373232(v=vs.85).aspx).

My question is: why am I getting these values back? The Windows battery tray icon displays the correct percentage, so why I can't get that data from here?

I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate Edition 64-bit.

Thank you.

Comment: 255 _is_ -1 if you read it as a byte value and properly sign-extend, rather than just plopping 0xff into a larger value bucket.

Comment: I understand the 255. I don't get the 0. That should be -1. Also, the question is why Kernel32 doesn't know the status of my battery. Thank you.

Comment: Check the mappings on the Kernel32 functions, someone might have gotten the size wrong on something and ended up reading the wrong byte, or neglected/added padding in a key structure.

Comment: I fixed the answer you found. Actually, the `getFieldOrder()` was only added in a later Windows version (the initial code snippet worked fine in XP but not in Vista/7) and I got it proposed by another user (10k users can see the deleted answer) and added it to the answer more than 2 years later without carefully testing the output. Sorry for that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code from the linked answer was wrong (**edit**: now 
it is fixed).

**The fields are ordered in the wrong way**, change `getFieldOrder` method with

```
@Override
protected List<String> getFieldOrder() 
{
    ArrayList<String> fields = new ArrayList<String>();
    fields.add("ACLineStatus");
    fields.add("BatteryFlag");
    fields.add("BatteryLifePercent");
    fields.add("Reserved1");
    fields.add("BatteryLifeTime");
    fields.add("BatteryFullLifeTime");
    return fields;
}
```

Also add this constructor that specify the correct alignment

```
 public SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS()
 {
    setAlignType(ALIGN_MSVC);
 }
```

The alignment could also be `ALIGN_NONE` as Microsoft usually take care to explicitly align data with *reserved* fields.
It could also be `ALIGN_DEFAULT` since, as far as I know, Windows is compiled with Microsoft compiler, and it aligns data on their the natural boundaries.

**In other words the structure is naturally aligned by design, so it requires no specific alignment constraints**.

---

This is the output, on my system, from the original code

> ACLineStatus: Offline
>       Battery Flag: High, more than 66 percent
>       Battery Life: Unknown
>       Battery Left: 0 seconds
>       Battery Full: 12434 seconds

This is the output with the corrected code

> ACLineStatus: Offline
>       Battery Flag: High, more than 66 percent
>       Battery Life: 95%
>       Battery Left: 12434 seconds
>       Battery Full: Unknown

---

### On why this happens

Considering the output above, we can reconstruct how the structure `SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS` is filled in memory.

```
    00 08 5f 00 96 30 00 00 ff ff ff ff
    ¯¯ ¯¯ ¯¯ ¯¯ ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯ ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
     |  | |  |          |             |   
     |  | |  |       BatteryLifeTime  |
     |  | | Reserved1                 |
     |  | |                      BatteryFullLifeTime     
     |  | BatteryLifePercent
     |  |
     | BatteryFlags
     |
 AcLineStatus
```

According to the fields order of the original code, this is how the fields get initialized

```
    00 08 5f 00 96 30 00 00 ff ff ff ff  00 00 00 00
    ¯¯ ¯¯       ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯ ¯¯           ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
    |  |             |      |                    |
    | BatteryFlags   |     BatteryLifePercent    |
    |                |                           |
AcLineStatus         |                         BatteryLifeTime
                 BatteryFullLifeTime
```

The gaps are due to the default alignment that align data on their natural boundaries.
Since the fields have been reordered they are no longer in their original positions and continuous.

### On why BatteryFullLifeTime is Unknown

If you disassemble the function `GetSystemPowerStatus` for Win7 64 bit (you can find my disassembly [here](http://pastebin.com/4GHS5xRR)) and rewrite an equivalent C program you got something like this

```c
BOOL WINAPI GetSystemPowerStatus(
  _Out_ LPSYSTEM_POWER_STATUS lpSystemPowerStatus
)
{
    SYSTEM_BATTERY_STATE battery_state;

    //Get power information
    NTStatus pi_status = NtPowerInformation(SystemBatteryState, NULL, 0, &battery_state, sizeof(battery_state));

    //Check success
    if (!NTSuccess(pi_status))
    {
        BaseSetLastNtError(pi_status);
        return FALSE;
    }

    //Zero out the input structure
    memset(lpSystemPowerStatus, sizeof(lpSystemPowerStatus), 0);

    //Set AC line status
    lpSystemPowerStatus->ACLineStatus = battery_state.BatteryPresent && battery_state.AcOnLine ? 1 : 0;

    //Set flags
    lpSystemPowerStatus->BatteryFlags   |=  (battery_state.Charging         ? 8 :    0) 
                                        |   (battery_state.BatteryPresent   ? 0 : 0x80);



    //Set battery life time percent
    lpSystemPowerStatus->BatteryLifePercent = 0xff;
    if (battery_state.MaxCapacity)
    {
        lpSystemPowerStatus->BatteryLifePercent = battery_state.RemainingCapacity > battery_state.MaxCapacity
                                                ? 100
                                                : (battery_state.RemainingCapacity*100 + battery_state.MaxCapacity/2)/battery_state.MaxCapacity;

        lpSystemPowerStatus->BatteryFlags   |=  (lpSystemPowerStatus->BatteryLifePercent > 66 ? 1 : 0) 
                                            |   (lpSystemPowerStatus->BatteryLifePercent < 33 ? 2 : 0);
    }

    //Set battery life time and full life time
    lpSystemPowerStatus->BatteryLifeTime = lpSystemPowerStatus->BatteryFullLifeTime = -1;

    if (battery_state.EstimatedTime)
        lpSystemPowerStatus->BatteryLifeTime = battery_state.EstimatedTime;
}
```

Which show that `BatterFullLifeTime` is never copied from the `SYSTEM_BATTERY_STATE` structure. It is always -1.
Also the flag with value 4 (Critical battery level) is never set.
In newer version of Windows these may have probably been fixed.

---

### A newer version

You can call `CallNtPowerInformation` in `PowrProf.dll` to obtain more reliable information on the battery status.

If you are unfamiliar with accessing the Win APIs, here a *JNA* class that do the work for you

**PowrProf.Java**

```java
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javaapplication5;

/**
 *
 * @author mijo
 */
import java.util.List;

import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.Structure;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;
import java.util.Arrays;

public interface PowrProf extends StdCallLibrary {

    public PowrProf INSTANCE = (PowrProf) Native.loadLibrary("PowrProf", PowrProf.class);


    public class SYSTEM_BATTERY_STATE extends Structure 
    {
        public static class ByReference extends SYSTEM_BATTERY_STATE implements Structure.ByReference {}

        public byte AcOnLine;
        public byte BatteryPresent;
        public byte Charging;
        public byte Discharging;

        public byte Spare1_0;
        public byte Spare1_1;
        public byte Spare1_2;
        public byte Spare1_3;

        public int   MaxCapacity;
        public int   RemainingCapacity;
        public int   Rate;
        public int   EstimatedTime;
        public int   DefaultAlert1;
        public int   DefaultAlert2;

        @Override
        protected List<String> getFieldOrder() 
        {
            return Arrays.asList(new String[]
            {
                "AcOnLine", "BatteryPresent", "Charging", "Discharging", 
                "Spare1_0", "Spare1_1", "Spare1_2", "Spare1_3", 
                "MaxCapacity", "RemainingCapacity", "Rate", 
                "EstimatedTime", "DefaultAlert1", "DefaultAlert2"
            });
        }

        public SYSTEM_BATTERY_STATE ()
        {
            setAlignType(ALIGN_MSVC);
        }

        public boolean isAcConnected()
        {
            return AcOnLine != 0;
        }

        public boolean isBatteryPresent()
        {
            return BatteryPresent != 0;
        }


        public enum BatteryFlow{ Charging, Discharging, None }

        public BatteryFlow getBatteryFlow()
        {
            if (Charging != 0)       return BatteryFlow.Charging;
            if (Discharging != 0)    return BatteryFlow.Discharging;

            return BatteryFlow.None;
        }

        //in mWh
        public int getMaxCapacity()
        {
            return MaxCapacity;
        }

        //in mWh
        public int getCurrentCharge()
        {
            return RemainingCapacity;
        }

        //in mW
        public int getFlowRate()
        {
            return Rate;
        }

        //in s
        public int getEstimatedTime()
        {
            return EstimatedTime;
        }

        //in s
        //-1 if not available
        public int getTimeToEmpty()
        {
            if (getBatteryFlow() != BatteryFlow.Discharging)
                return -1;

            return -getCurrentCharge()*3600/getFlowRate();
        }

        //in s
        //-1 if not available
        public int getTimeToFull()
        {
            if (getBatteryFlow() != BatteryFlow.Charging)
                return -1;

            return (getMaxCapacity()-getCurrentCharge())*3600/getFlowRate();
        }

        public double getCurrentChargePercent()
        {
            return getCurrentCharge()*100/getMaxCapacity();
        }

        public int getCurrentChargeIntegralPercent()
        {
            return (getCurrentCharge()*100+getMaxCapacity()/2)/getMaxCapacity();
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(4096);

            b.append("AC Line? "); b.append(isAcConnected());
            b.append("\nBattery present? "); b.append(isBatteryPresent());
            b.append("\nBattery flow: "); b.append(getBatteryFlow());
            b.append("\nMax capacity (mWh): "); b.append(getMaxCapacity());
            b.append("\nCurrent charge (mWh): "); b.append(getCurrentCharge());
            b.append("\nFlow rate (mW/s): "); b.append(getFlowRate());
            b.append("\nEstimated time (from OS): "); b.append(getEstimatedTime());
            b.append("\nEstimated time (manual): "); b.append(getTimeToEmpty());
            b.append("\nEstimated time to full (manual): "); b.append(getTimeToFull());
            b.append("\nCurrent charge (percent): "); b.append(getCurrentChargePercent());
            b.append("\nCurrent charge (integral percent): "); b.append(getCurrentChargeIntegralPercent());

            return b.toString();
        }
    }

    public int CallNtPowerInformation(int informationLevel, Pointer  inBuffer, long inBufferLen, SYSTEM_BATTERY_STATE.ByReference  outBuffer, long outBufferLen);

    static final int SystemBatteryState = 5;

    public static SYSTEM_BATTERY_STATE GetBatteryState()
    {
        SYSTEM_BATTERY_STATE.ByReference battery_state = new SYSTEM_BATTERY_STATE.ByReference();

        int retVal = PowrProf.INSTANCE.CallNtPowerInformation(SystemBatteryState, Pointer.NULL, 0, battery_state, battery_state.size());

        if (retVal != 0)
            return null;

        return battery_state;
    }
}
```

And its use

```java
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    PowrProf.SYSTEM_BATTERY_STATE sbs = PowrProf.GetBatteryState();

    System.out.println(sbs);
}
```

Sample output when discharging:

> AC Line? false
>       Battery present? true
>       Battery flow: Discharging
>       Max capacity (mWh): 35090
>       Current charge (mWh): 34160
>       Flow rate (mW/s): -11234
>       Estimated time (from OS): 10940
>       Estimated time (manual): 10946
>       Estimated time to full (manual): -1
>       Current charge (percent): 97.34
>       Current charge (integral percent): 98

Sample output when charging:

> AC Line? true
>       Battery present? true
>       Battery flow: Charging
>       Max capacity (mWh): 35090
>       Current charge (mWh): 33710
>       Flow rate (mW/s): 3529
>       Estimated time (from OS): -1
>       Estimated time (manual): -1
>       Estimated time to full (manual): 1407 
>       Current charge (percent): 96.06
>       Current charge (integral percent): 97

---

**N.B.** When plugging and unplugging the power cable to test, wait some sec as the monitoring is not in real time.

*P.S.*
I sign my code with the pseudonym *Mijo*, you can remove that comment.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your explanation is really interesting and you clearly put a lot of effort into it. It's really appreciated. Unfortunately, I think I'll stick to Kernel32 because I need the battery percentage and also I'm not interested in raw physical data at the moment. But that's good to know for future usages. +1 and accepted.

Comment: @Aurasphere I added the percentage. Honestly I had left it out because I assumed you knew how to compute percentages :)

Comment: Whoops... My bad... Ahahha Thank you! xP

Comment: FYI: referenced answer has in the meanwhile been fixed. Thank you for the explanation too!