# Java events on plug/unplug power adapter for notebook

Tags: java, windows-7, power-management, battery

I want my application to respond to plugging/unplugging power adapter to notebook.
Is there any suitable libraries or classes in Java for that action? The OS is Win7

Comment: Check ***[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160302/monitoring-battery-or-power-supply-of-laptop-from-java)*** post