# Is it possible to make Intellij enter power save mode when my laptop is on battery automatically?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-16

I usually work with the AC plugged in but sometimes I remove the cord and forget to put Intellij into Power Save mode and my battery drains battery very quickly. Is it possible to do what I am asking?

Comment: You will have to write a plugin and use something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160302/monitoring-battery-or-power-supply-of-laptop-from-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please [follow this feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-119217) for updates.

There is a [link to a dummy plug-in](https://github.com/algi/powersource-monitor-intellij) for Mac that you can modify to make it actually switch the power save mode, right now it can only monitor the system events, but doesn't perform any actions.

Comment: That's great. I'm on Linux. I'll look forward to the feature request.

Comment: There is an [Automatic Power Saver](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/11941-automatic-power-saver) plugin suggested in the linked issue.

Comment: @Vadzim That's a neat tool, but it focuses on application state and not the power status of the machine.