# using java on any OS how to check if the machine is a laptop or a desk

Tags: java, jlink

I am writing a program to gather information specific to a laptop, linux server, desktop, workstation. The first step is to identify where my program is running. I am having trouble achieving this part. If you could point me in the right direction, would be very helpful.

I realize there might not be one solution and have to probably combine multiple solutions.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I would try and detect the battary status (no status means desktop). You can refer to this answer on how to accomplis this:
[Monitoring battery or power supply of laptop from java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160302/monitoring-battery-or-power-supply-of-laptop-from-java)

Comment: One caveat is when a desktop uses a smart UPS (using USB to report capacity), modern operating systems will treat that like like a laptop battery. I use a CyberPower smart UPS and Win10 lets me set power options (like sleep and shutdown) based on battery levels.